# what's the #text height & width unit measured in chrome?

Tags: css

I don't know why chrome shows the #text has 206.53x88 width and height, I'd like to know their units, it just can't be px.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  line-height: 80px;
}

span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span> 
  czvzx
</div>
```

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: it's pixel ....

Comment: Hello, I just  put the picture here, can you plz see picture1? I think it can't be pixel, it's weird.

Comment: the text can't get a 88px of height,as pic1 shows, for its parent div has only 80px of height.

Comment: are you zooming? if it's seems you have 200% of zoom

Comment: no, I specially checked if I zoomed the page, before I asked the question.

Comment: it's probably because of the `line-height` adding to it's height. but i wouldn't be so sure because the code you provide shows nothing off.